# Form does not submit using javascript on safari only

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I can't figure out why this is not working only in safari, I have a form like this:

```
<form action="https://nakupa.co/browse-ads/" id="home--search-form" class="labeled-main-search flex-wrap">
   <input type="hidden" value="1" name="aff-cpt">
   <div>
      <label for="keyword">Mot clé</label>
      <div class="keyword-wrap"> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="keyword" placeholder="Rechercher..."></div>
   </div>
   <div>
      <label for="location">Lieu</label>
      <div class="header-location"> <input type="text" class="form-control place-lookup location pac-target-input" name="location" placeholder="Situé à..." autocomplete="off"> <input type="hidden" name="latitude" class="latitude" value="43.641906726879895"> <input type="hidden" name="longitude" class="longitude" value="-0.44476782060628417"></div>
   </div>
   <div>
      <label for="category">Catégorie</label>
      <div class="styled-select">
         <select name="category">
            <option value="">Dans la Catégorie</option>
            <option value="236">Plats et pâtisseries maison</option>
            <option value="238">&nbsp;&nbsp;Gâteaux et pâtisseries</option>
            <option value="237">&nbsp;&nbsp;Plats et restauration</option>
            <option value="246">Produits de la ferme</option>
            <option value="248">&nbsp;&nbsp;Poulet fermier</option>
            <option value="216">Produits de la mer</option>
            <option value="218">&nbsp;&nbsp;Crabes, langoustes et fruits de mer</option>
            <option value="176">Produits des champs</option>
            <option value="214">&nbsp;&nbsp;Fruits et légumes</option>
            <option value="213">&nbsp;&nbsp;Ignames parates taros</option>
            <option value="231">Sculptures et artisanat d'art</option>
            <option value="234">&nbsp;&nbsp;Artisanat d'art</option>
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="search-submit"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="af-button submit-form">Recherche</a></div>
</form>
```

I have a piece of js that submits any parent form like this:

```
    $(document).on('click', '.submit-ajax-form, .submit-form', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parents('form').submit();
    });
```

It works on anything except safari, and I can't understand why. The event is fired properly, when I click on the button it will even log the current target or the parent form if I add that into this piece of js, but it does not submit, and worse, sometimes it works somehow. If I click on the header link to go to the same page (homepage), it will then work.
Example scenario:

- New safari private tab
- Cookie popup shows, there if I click the search button without accepting cookie notice, it works
- If I accept cookie notice, the page reloads, and loads google analytics js, and from there, it won't work.
- BUT: If I reload the page now, it works!

Behaviour is similar on iOS simulator (iPhone SE 2nd gen)

Did anyone experience something similar?

Comment: Missing an 'S' in the title. I have problems with Safari and sometimes with Chrome when using 'a' tag as button to a JavaScript function. Now I use only buttons.

Comment: Explain what you mean by “parent form”? You are not actually _nesting_ `form` elements into each other, are you?

Comment: @CBroe No I am not, I mean the enclosing form.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by replacing the a tag with a button tag as suggested by [Gustavo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1572493/gustavo)